# FPDF how to change directory path of image to to put it from folder in PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using fpdf for converting images to pdf, it is working perfectly but it is taking the path of images in root folder only.
I have stored my images in subfolder root/docs/pancards

so how do I change the directory path in code
$image is path to image

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
//$image = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'my_image.png';
$image = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'4-add11.png';
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($image,20,40,170,170);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Thanks in advance..